# What is the difference between Article 10 and Article 11 of the Indian Constitution

Tags: constitutional-law, india

I am from a non law background and reading Indian Constitution. After reading Laxmikanth and PM Bakshi, what I could get is that both the Articles deals with law made by parliament related to Citizenship but I am unable to get the finer details of it.

What was the need to make 2 articles? If someone can explain with an example that would be most welcome.

Comment: One goes up to 11. It's not ten. Where can you go from there? Where? Nowhere. Exactly! When we need that extra push over the cliff, you know what we do? Put it up to eleven? Exactly! One louder.

Comment: Sorry. But I didn't get it.

Comment: @JayChakra It's an entirely off-topic irrelevant joke.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_Spinal_Tap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Article 10 says that anybody meeting the definition of a citizen under Part 2 of the constitution will become or will continue to be a citizen unless Parliament makes a law that removes the person's citizenship.

Article 11 says that Parliament may make any laws regarding who is and is not a citizen, and why or how, without limitation by the Constitution.

The first is necessary because it ensured continuity from time prior to the constitution being adopted. The second is necessary because it ensures Parliament may continue to manage citizenships after that point (i.e. to do its job).

Comment: Okey. So basically the two laws are differentiated in time. Putting in simple words, Article 10 authorises parliament to manage citizenship of those before commencement of the constitution whereas Article 11 authorises parliament to manage citizenship after the commencement of constitution by means of law

Comment: No. Article 10 defines who has citizenship **at** the commencement, 11 makes clear that Parliament *may* define citizenship *after* it.